# D3 - not all children nodes are shown at the same time

Tags: json, d3.js, nodes, children

I'm trying to create a network graph based on this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130). 
I tried using this json file that I have but it doesn't show all nodes at the same times.

```html
{
  "name":"Plant",
  "children":[
    {
      "name":"Delonix regia",
      "children": [
        {
        "id" : "Family",
        "name" : "Fabaceae",
        "size": 10000
        },
        {
        "id" : "Common Name",
        "name" : "Semarak api",
        "size": 10000
        },
        {
        "id" : "Habitat",
        "name" : "Humid",
        "size": 10000
        }
        ]
    },
      {
        "name":"Ixora javanica",
          "children": [
            {
            "id" : "Family",
            "name" : "Fabaceae",
            "size": 10000
            },
            {
            "id" : "Common Name",
            "name" : "Bunga air",
            "size": 10000
            },
            {
            "id" : "Habitat",
            "name" : "Hot",
            "size": 10000
            }
            ]
      },
      {
        "name":"Dracaena reflexa",
          "children": [
            {
            "id" : "Family",
            "name" : "Asparagaceae",
            "size": 10000
            },
            {
            "id" : "Common Name",
            "name" : "Pleomele",
            "size": 10000
            },
            {
            "id" : "Habitat",
            "name" : "Unknown",
            "size": 10000
            }
            ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Here is how it looks.

[image]

When I click at other parent node `Delonix regia` or `Ixora javanica` another node that is opened will close.

I have another json that is more complicated but it works well and all nodes are showing.

How can I make all nodes or only parent nodes are shown?

Comment: show us the code, this has nothing to do we data.

Comment: @ChiragKothari added the link to the example. Didn't change anything except name of the json file I have.

Comment: Maybe it's because you used `"title":` rather than `"name":`

Comment: @shians you mean like `"title":"Dracaena reflexa"` ? Nope, I already tried that but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated code provided in example and added your json as datasource. It is working fine - https://jsfiddle.net/zLehvLtd/

I have replaced id with name at two places in the code:

```
// Update links.
 link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.name; });

// Update nodes.
node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Other method to create a complete tree is to add unique "id" for each object in json. The reason behind this is that d3.js accepts json in nested format with atleast one unique property for each object.

Comment: Ohh, I see. then, it's either to change `id` to `name` or I should add `id` to each object, right?

Comment: but i noticed that `family` in `ixora javanica` is not showing.

Comment: Yes @kaixasK. Changing `id` to `name` worked because each object had a unique key `name`. It doesn't matter whats the unique key called. So replacing `id` with `name` in `links` and `node` (which require a unique key) helped us build a tree. If you think that `name` might be same for two objects in future then its a good idea to follow second approach and add unique `id` for each object. Hope it helps!

Comment: @kaixasK Ah Its because of the same reason as I explained in above comment. "name" : "Fabaceae" is same for both "Delonix regia" and "Ixora javanica" so d3 is showing first unique object which is under "Delonix regia".  Changing "name" : "Fabaceae1" under  "Ixora javanica" shows it in tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply delete `"id":` field then it will work. Otherwise you need to assign unique ids to each node you wish to display.